# An issue when using TeXnicCenter Alpha and Adobe Reader 10

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texniccenter, viewers

I use TeXnicCenter Alpha, [DDE control TeXnicCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998678/dde-control-texnic-center), MikteX 2.7, Adobe Reader 10, and Windows 7. Whenever I build, the log file reads "`undefined !control sequence`" and whenever I output the file, the Adobe Reader will pop up, but the document is not shown, and when I close the Adobe Reader, then TeXnicCenter will not respond. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean you are using the alpha version of TeXnicCenter 2?  I have two recommendations: TXC works nicely with [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html), so you might cosnider installing it for previewing your pdfs. And MiKTeX 2.7 is heavily outdated, you should update to the [newest MiKTeX version](http://miktex.org/).

Comment: It might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43872/9467

Comment: And the current version of the Adobe Reader is `X (10.1.2)` (maybe you wanted to say this with `10`, otherwise use the Reader's update function).

Comment: @matth, Your advise works well.. thanks a lot for the links..I can now use the miktext.. btw,where can I find some packages like graphtex and the like?

Comment: @KenethAdrian You can find the [graphtex package on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphtex), the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DDE commands that control acrobat 10 changed compared to older versions. You can have a look [here](http://www.golatex.de/texniccenter-2-0a3-und-miktex-2-9-t5482,start,25.html).

This document is written in German, but I think the figures are self explaining. From that document, Figure 25 shows the settings[image]

Apparently it is also required to go in the acrobat settings and check a box "start savemode at start-up" (may be called slightly different) in the general settings tab.