# Debug an error due to new column type definition

Tags: tables, texniccenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MiKTeX / TeXnicCenter / Adobe Reader: No pdf produced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73020/miktex-texniccenter-adobe-reader-no-pdf-produced)

I introduced new column types as following

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3cm} }
\newcolumntype{n}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{4.2cm} }
```

so that it allows me to vertically and horizontally align text in a table with graphics included.

I use these packages for tables:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

and I use the latest version of TeXnicCenter editor.

And I wrote the following table:

```
\begin{table}[here]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[here]{C n n}

\toprule
state & image & parameters \\
\midrule
abc & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{1.pdf} & 123 \\\midrule
cdf  & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{2.pdf}  &  345 \\\midrule
fgh & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{3.pdf}  &  567 \\\midrule
hij & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{4.pdf}  &  789 \\\buttomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I liked the table I got, it is just what I need 
but I have some errors due to that! First I was unable to compile the pdf file directly! I should first close the pdf and then compile and then open it.

How can I debug such an error??

Comment: thanks for the  hints but it does not seem to help !

I still have same number of errors and warnings ! but the good thing is that I am once more able to compile and view the pdf without closing it !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. Regarding the question, the `[here]` option doesn't exist; it can be `[htbp]` for `table`, but only `[t]` or `[b]` for `tabular`. Remove both and try again. But the problem seems to have nothing to do with the table: it's linked to Adobe Reader that locks the PDF file.

Comment: You have misspelt `\bottomrule` at the end of your example.