# TeXnicCenter cannot automatically open PDF in Adobe Reader

Tags: texniccenter

I am attempting to automatically open a PDF after recompilation using TeXnicCenter. If I compile using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, I can go into the directory of the PDF and it opens fine, but if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to "Build and View", the PDF won't open, and I get the error message "Cannot execute the command":

[image: screenshot of error message]

I have just reinstalled my Adobe, so this shouldn't (?) be an issue. This happens with both `LaTex => PDF` and `XeLaTeX => PDF` options.

*Update*: Here are my DDE settings:

[image]

Comment: Close down TeXnicCenter; restart it, and try again.

Comment: That didn't work. I also restarted my computer.

Comment: ah the wonderful DDE commands, I don't have TeXnicCenter at hand at the moment, but there is an option to use command line arguments instead of these commands I believe, you could try that. Or maybe try something like [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html), which also provides inverse search with the correct configuration.

Comment: @hugovdberg: Yes, I am with, SumatraPDF is the best program here, but the question was not for inverse-search.

Comment: No problem here, could you post your DDE settings, please? I do not understand your phrase “go into the directory of the PDF”, though, because it should open without explicitly doing this. And do you use Adobe Reader (as i assumed in my edit of the title) or Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: I am using Adobe Reader. I am posting what I believe to be my DDE settings; what are DDE settings, by the way?

Comment: If you have just installed adobe, do you maybe have the newest version which is 11? Maybe just get this version and change all 10 to 11. The rest does look good for me...

Comment: Changed all 10 to 11. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @NickThompson: Apart from that I have Adobe Reader 11 (LaRiFaRi gave a hint) my settings are the same, and, already said, I observe no problem. Of course, Adobe Reader 11 is actually installed here. Therefore: I do not have a clue, what your problem is.

Comment: @NickThompson: Ha, how could I forget the protected mode of Adobe Reader! See answers to [TeXnicCenter & Adobe Acrobat 10](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43864). If you are a MiKTeX user then see additionally [MiKTeX / TeXnicCenter / Adobe Reader: No pdf produced](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73020).

Comment: I turned off Adobe Protected mode. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Could we unclose this question, since the recommended answers are not working?