# texnic-center doesn't output pdf when acrobat already opened

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, acrobat

When I try to view an output file of pdf type and at the same time I have a pdf file opened nothing happens: my output isn't opened or shown.

I can modify the profiles of texnic-center related to tes->pdf viewer, DDE command or the command line arguments,

in order to be able to open view output in a new acrobat window ?

Comment: Acrobat locks the file when it open it. You have either to change PDF-view (try Sumantra) or close Adobe before you compile the document after viewing. Take a look at [this question and answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc)

Comment: If you want to use Adobe with TeXnicCenter then you have to change the profile to close Adobe Acrobat.  Better use SumatraPDF, then the pdf file can stay open and is automatic changed after the compile has finished. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166490/texniccenter-cannot-automatically-open-pdf-in-adobe-reader?rq=1