# TeXnicCenter & Adobe Reader DC in 2020

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, adobe

This question is similar to this one:
[TeXnicCenter & Adobe Reader DC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc).

> How to configure TeXnicCenter to work with Adobe Reader DC?

I have used the solution(s) listed on that linked question many times in the past.  However, the solutions no longer work.  This may be due to a recent upgrade to Windows 10, or because the Adobe Reader version is wrong.

What I have tried:

- Checking the location of AcroRd32.exe (it is still in the same folder)
- Changing the server to `acroviewR19`. (If I open AcroRd32.exe, the version at the top is `19.021.20061`.  Before the OS upgrade, I was successfully using `acroviewR19` as the server.)
- Changing the server to `acroviewR20`.  This opens Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (if it is not already open) while TeXnicCenter hangs for about 20 seconds before showing the same error message.
- Changing all 5 instances of `%bm` to `%tm` on the viewer tab of Profiles based on the suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73020/miktex-texniccenter-adobe-reader-no-pdf-produced) (even though that related to BibTeX, not the output viewer).
- Setting packages to be automatically installed on-the-fly (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/texniccenter-adobe-acrobat-10); this was the setting I had previously when it worked).  (i.e. MiKTeX Console > Settings > General tab > "Always install missing packages on-the-fly").

Regardless of what I do, I get the same error message as on the other post:

[image]

If I use `acroviewR19`, I sometimes see this error message first before getting the one above:

> There was an error opening this document.  This file cannot be found.

I've applied the latest OS updates and restarted my computer.

Comment: I was previously using Windows 7, where acroviewR19 worked.

Comment: When I compile my document, it compiles without errors or warnings (LaTeX and BibTeX). But no PDF or related Tex files are produced.

Comment: I have (in win10, not in texniccenter but in winedt) currently `AcroviewR19` as server and it still works.

Comment: Could you post a screenshoot of the settings?
I just did a fresh install and cannot make the pdf open
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rodolfo The screenshot is the same as in the answer to the linked question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc, with the only change being `acroviewR19` as the server rather than `acroviewR15`.

Comment: acroviewR21 was working but now I have not Acrord32.exe but Acrobat.exe. Is there a server for this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a completely fresh installation (TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX). LaTeX now successfully compiles and builds the PDF output.

Before I did the reinstall, I took screen captures of the output profile settings.  It worked with both Adobe Acrobat `acroviewA11` (default) and Adobe Reader `acroviewR19` (which is now identical to the old installation).

The forced upgrade to Windows 10 must have broken something.  But I don't know what.  If you have the same problem, my advice is to bite the bullet and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

For people who are facing this problem in 2021, it is necessary to change "acroviewR20" to "acroviewR21" that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 after the latest updates on 12th Feb 2020. Acrobat reader had silently upgraded to release 20. So just replace the server string in the DDE command with "acroviewR20". You find it in Output --> Profiles --> Viewer.

Comment: As I said in the question, I tried this and it did not work for me. My version of Adobe hadn’t changed, so acroviewR19 was still correct. Glad it solved your issue though.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the answer to this thread ([Texnic center and Adobe Acrobat DC, again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618616/texnic-center-and-adobe-acrobat-dc-again)) if AcroViewR21 didn't work, try AcroViewA21. This of course can change to 22 instead of 21 with the new year if the reader is updated to a newer version.
The final way to know which value is to look for your reader in the Registry. For example, in my case, (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat2021.oauth2\shell\open\ddeexec\application)

Comment: This solution USUALLY worked for me too. I'd used it several times successfully. But when I posted this question, it did not.  I believe the cause was the Win 10 upgrade.

Comment: I see. It looks like in your case something was different. However, I posted this answer to anyone still suffering from this issue and will find your question when they search. The change from "R" to "A" will also be new for some people.

Comment: Ah, I missed the subtle change from "R" to "A".  Yes, maybe that will be helpful to others.  Thanks for sharing your solution.