# Texnic center and Adobe Acrobat DC, again

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, adobe, acrobat

It is a common problem that TexnicCenter fails to call Adobe Acrobat Reader as the pdf viewer:

> [DocOpen("%bm.pdf")]... Cannot execute the command.

This happens often when there is an update to Reader. See, e.g.
[TeXnicCenter & Adobe Reader DC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [TeXnicCenter & Adobe Reader DC in 2020](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525310/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc-in-2020?rq=1)

I know that this can be fixed by changing the name of the "server" in the viewer output profile. This is how I have fixed it every time before. Currently I have it as "acroviewR21", which has worked this year until today. Usually it can be fixed just by updating the year, but since it is still 2021 (as is my version of acrobat reader DC), I am really not sure what to do. I have tried various permutations of the capitalization to no effect. I have tried making it 22 with no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered to use another pdf viewer, for example PDFSumatra?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I use Adobe Reader for reasons that matter to me and would prefer to see if anyone has the right suggestion here. I'm willing to try PDFSumatra, but do you have an up-to-date link for how to configure PDFSumatra for use with TexnicCenter? There are very complicated 5-year old walkthroughs here on tex.se that tell you what changes need to be made to get the instructions in the 8-year old walkthroughs to work...! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-2016-version . Is there a straightforward link?

Comment: Check the following instruction: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF%20with%20TeXnicCenter.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try acroviewA21.  On 2021-10-25, acroviewR21 stopped woring for me, and acroviewA21 started working for me.  I found this by looking at the Registry, per Joshua González's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. More insidiously an update also changed the path of my reader installation, so the combination of these two things made this really annoying. I appreciate everyone else who helped.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct server name can be consulted in the Registry.

For Adobe Acrobat DC, such key is located in:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application]
```

I believe that there should be a similar path for Reader, but I encourage corrections.

Salutations.

Comment: For the very last acrobat DC update (2021.007. ) they changed quite a few things. 
The executable is now, finally, 64bits, located at 

/program files/Adobe/Adobe DC/Acrobat.exe, 

the server id is now 

AcroviewA21 (instead of R21). 

and the related registry key is located at

[Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\] or [Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\] followed by [..\acrobat2021.oauth2\shell\open\ddeexec\application]

(and it doesn't help that, when you update the reader, it doesn't remove old keys... so the odds of getting fooled with the wrong/old key are 'good').

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to synchronize this answer with my update [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255615/87876) because it violates DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) design principle. So please visit the given link for the latest update.

#### Latest Update (March 17, 2022)

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 64-bit version **2022.001.20085**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This work's for me. Thank's

[image: Configuration for "Server"]

This is my ADobe Reader version:

[image: Version Adobe Reader]

Answer (score 1):

For Adobe Acrobat Pro (32 bit), version 2023.001.20093.0 it is AcroViewA23. Note the capital letters A ad V in AcroView. This is different to earlier versions.