# TeXnicCenter Adobe Acrobat not working: "Cannot Execute The Command"

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, adobe

*I have a deadline to meet, so please be sympathetic if this is a low quality question.*

Since I'm having the same problem, I have tried variations of the suggestions here:

- [Texnic center and Adobe Acrobat DC, again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618616/39761)
- [TeXnicCenter & Adobe Reader DC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250472/39761)
- [TeXnicCenter & Adobe Acrobat 10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43864/39761)

I have had no success.

### Here is my latest attempt:

**Executable path:**

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe
```

**View project's output, server:**

```
acroviewR22
```

**Forward search, server:**

```
acroviewR22
```

**Close document before running (La)TeX:**

```
acroviewR22
```

**Here's a screenshot:**

[image]

Please help :)

Comment: I have `AcroviewR22` (with uppercase A) as dde name (this is from a current reader). But you don't have to use adobe, you could also use sumatra, or another editor.

Comment: Thank you. That didn't work, @UlrikeFischer, although I might not have the right "executable path". Which do you use?

Comment: even if I have another path: it doesn't matter where the reader is installed on my machine but where it is one yours. Check also the version. Do you really already have the 2022 version?

Comment: I don't know, @UlrikeFischer.

Comment: How do I find out, @UlrikeFischer?

Comment: like all other applications the adobe reader has a menu and there an entry showing "info about ...".

Comment: Thank you for the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to synchronize this answer with my update [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255615/87876) because it violates DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) design principle. So please visit the given link for the latest update.

#### Latest Update (March 17, 2022)

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 64-bit version **2022.001.20085**:

[image]

### Edit

[image]

Comment: If this answer is helpful, don't forget to deliver your bounty to me. :-)

Comment: I can only award the bounty after four hours from now. It's as good as yours though. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @Shaun: Thank you!

Comment: `...A22` is for acrobat pro, the reader uses `...R22`.  So it depends on what you actually have.

Comment: The path you show above in your screenshot is `...\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe`, and that is acrobat pro, the reader has the path `...\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe`  (I have both too, so I can compare).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did not change anything, I accepted the default location.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: See [my last edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc/255615#255615). Path and server code suffix are platform dependent (whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit).