# PDF viewer with auto update for WinEdt

Tags: pdf, viewers, winedt

Is there a PDF viewer featuring auto update for WinEdt? [WinEdt V 5.5 on WinVista machine]

I find WinEdt very comfortable to work with but the fact that one has to re-open Acrobat after every compilation and jump to the correct page is a big nuisance!

Comment: When I was a windows' user I used Foxit and I remember that just swap the windows to update the PDF file. Check if this is still available.

Comment: Sumatrapdf !!!!!!!!

Comment: Are they easy to configure under WinEdt? I mean one has to tell WinEdt somehow that it should use them instead of the default pdf viewer which is Acrobat Reader ...

Comment: I'd say that configuring WinEdt to choose a PDF viewer other than Acrobat (Reader) is among its easier configuration tasks. However, no longer version 5.5 of WinEdt -- the current version is 7, and well worth it -- I can't tell you how to perform the job.

Comment: Don't want to upgrade to V 7 right now since I am currently finishing a major project and don't want to change my tools ...

Comment: might be useful info: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73817/6621](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73817/6621)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adobe is not designed to work with winedt or tex, but sumatrapdf is. I suggest using sumatrapdf with winedt. It also works seemlessly with forward and inverse search features.

## With winedt 5.x:

Download [sumatrapdf from this site](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html), and install. Open winedt, go to `Options` --->  `Execution Modes`:

[image]

In the window that opens, click the `Acrobat` tab and make the paths to sumatrapdf available as in this picture:

[image]

Once the paths are set, click OK and your winedt will start using sumatrapdf as the viewer.

Comment: See also http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/WinEdt/message/8582 In order to avoid problems with WinEdt opening SumatraPDF note http://www.winedt.org/temp/

Comment: Just want to confirm how great `SumatraPDF` works in combination with `WinEdt` and `LaTeX`!! It's even much better than `YAP` for `dvi`! Moreover, I have a slide with a converted `pstricks` picture and with `Acrobat` there was always some strange thing namely for this particular slide the colours in the `beamer` beader bar changed slightly. This is no longer the case with `SumatraPDF`. So it's really a great viewer!

Comment: Sorry, I am repeating myself :-) `SumatraPDF` is REALLY great! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Now that [evince](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/tools/evince-windows) for   windows is available, I can just recommend it. This is a great viewer (not just for pdfs) that has auto-update functionality. This is helpful, when you are compiling your tex and producing new pdf of your text.

Answer (score 2):

**With WinEdt 10.1**

Goto Options -> Execution Mode -> PDF Viewer

Now put/define the path of the executable file for SumatraPDF as shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Latest version 10.3 will also auto configure SumatraPDF with additional syntax see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464909/170109